# Installing and using godef

Tags: go

I install godef:

```
$ go get -u github.com/rogpeppe/godef
```

Looks great:

```
$ which godef
/home/username/go/bin/godef
```

Right where I expect it:

```
$ echo $GOPATH
/home/username/go
```

But when called as a command line tool:

```
$ godef version
godef: cannot read : open : no such file or directory
```

What's happening?

Comment: What are you expecting to happen? You're not giving it any source, and what is `version`?

Comment: I'm expecting it to operate as a command line binary, so I can figure out why it isn't working.  I am trying to debug, when in emacs, and I run C-c C-d, which should show me the godef at point, I get "Could not run godef binary"

Comment: `version` isn't a valid argument on its own, unless you're looking for the `version` declaration in a source file and provided the source too. See the example in the docs: https://godoc.org/github.com/rogpeppe/godef

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest you to read the documentation found here: https://github.com/rogpeppe/godef/blob/master/doc.go

You can also try typing `godef -h`.

If you want more information, please explain what you are actually trying to do.

*EDIT: Regarding your comment above, I think that this library can't help you to accomplish what you are trying to do.*

Comment: I understand godef to describe at point:
godef-describe (C-c C-d) to describe expressions

https://github.com/dominikh/go-mode.el

Comment: Well I think that godef is made to find declarations and/or expressions in a go file. If I'm not mistaken, this is helpful on big projects.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into an issue trying to use `godef-describe (C-c C-d)` which would output the following error:

```
No description found for expression at point
```

If I tried using `godef` directly on a file, I would receive the following error:

```
% godef -f path/to/file.go "SomeFunction()"
2020/08/26 14:57:46 internal error: nil Pkg importing "io" from "github.com/some/package"
```

I fixed this by reinstalling `godef` and using the `master` branch as described [here](https://github.com/rogpeppe/godef/issues/118#issuecomment-595222101):

```
go get -v github.com/rogpeppe/godef@master
```

Answer (score 1):

since the latest updates on go and go.mod you might want to install it on your user so you should use `install` instead of `get`

if you want to install `godef` to your `gopath`:

`go install -v github.com/rogpeppe/godef@master`